Pointwise and $L^2$-norm convergence of Fourier series, which one is stronger?
I'm studying second edition of "Signals & Systems" by Oppenheim et al. Two classes of Fourier series convergence are introduced in Chapter 3. I'm somehow confused about the relation of these two.
One is pointwise convergence and the other, which is not given a name in the book, is based on the energy of the error signal (I think it must be named $L^2$-norm convergence. Correct me if I'm wrong.).
As quoted from the text on page 199 about pointwise convergence:
"For a periodic signal that has no discontinuities, the Fourier series representation converges and equals the original signal at every value of $t$. For a periodic signal with a finite number of discontinuities in each period, the Fourier series representation equals the signal everywhere except at the isolated points of discontinuity, at which the series converges to the average value of the signal on either side of the discontinuity.
In this case (the pointwise convergence case),  the difference between the original signal and its Fourier series representation contains no energy, and consequently, the two signals can be thought of as being the same for all practical purposes.".
So, I concluded that pointwise convergence is stronger, i.e., pointwise convergence $\implies$ $L^2$-norm convergence. Am I right?
I thought so until I came across the below signal: $x(t)=1/\sqrt{t}$ for $0 < t < 1$. If we make it periodic by repeating the signal in the above range, then we find a signal that satisfies Dirichlet conditions. Most importantly,
$$\int_0^1 |x(t)| dt=2\sqrt(t)|_0^1=2.$$
Thus, Fourier series representation of $x(t)$ converges in a pointwise manner. However, $x(t)$ does not satisfy the sufficient condition for the $L^2$-norm convergence, i.e.,
$$\int_0^1|x(t)|^2dt=\infty.$$
As the above condition is not necessary for $L^2$-norm convergence, I have nothing to say about the convergence. Does it converge in the second manner?
To wrap up:
Which convergence is stronger? Please give a counterexample showing that the other is not stronger. If no one is stronger, please give two counterexamples.
Thank you

I don’t know that one necessarily implies the other. For example take a periodic square wave that has value either 1 or -1. It would seem to be square integrable but not pointwise. Maybe someone will correct me on that though.

Is this question and its answer what you're looking for? I think for this question, math.se is probably a better place.

The question you mentioned covers the main aspect of mine and I had missed it. However, math.se questions and answers are hard for me to understand.

You're right about the type of convergence mentioned in the book. Considering the energy of the error means we're talking about the $L^2$-error norm:
$$\epsilon_N = \int_0^T\left|x(t)-\sum_{n=-N}^{N}c_ne^{j2\pi nt/T}\right|^2dt$$
where $c_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of the $T$-periodic function $x(t)$.
Convergence in the $L^2$-norm means
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\epsilon_N=0$$
The three types of convergence usually discussed in the context of Fourier series are:

uniform convergence
pointwise convergence
convergence in the mean ($L^2$-norm convergence)

Uniform convergence is the strongest of the three, and it implies the other two. Uniform convergence is guaranteed if the Fourier coefficients are absolutely summable, i.e., if
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|c_n|<\infty$$
Note that this is certainly the case if the Fourier coefficients decay at least as $1/n^2$.
Considering pointwise convergence and convergence in the mean, in the most general case, none of them is stronger than the other. It seems intuitive that convergence in the mean doesn't necessarily imply pointwise convergence, but also the opposite is true: pointwise convergence doesn't always imply convergence in the mean.
Examples for both cases can be found here and here.
However, from this question on math.se and its answer, we can conclude that if the partial sums of the Fourier series are bounded, i.e., if
$$\left|\sum_{n=-N}^{N}c_ne^{j2\pi nt/T}\right|<B<\infty$$
then pointwise convergence implies $L^2$ convergence.

Thank you for your response. Does it mean that if a signal satisfies Dirichlet's conditions for pointwise convergence AND it does not goes to infinity anywhere, then pointwise convergence implies the $L^2$-norm convergence?

@Robert: Yes, I believe you're right. It is also supported by this document.
